# Why does joblib.Parallel() take much more time than a non-paralleled computation? Shouldn't Parallel() run faster than a non-paralleled computation?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, parallelism-amdahl

A [**`joblib`**](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parallel.html) module provides a simple helper class to write parallel for loops using multiprocessing.

This code uses a list comprehension to do the job :

```
import time
from math import sqrt
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

start_t = time.time()
list_comprehension = [sqrt(i ** 2) for i in range(1000000)]
print('list comprehension: {}s'.format(time.time() - start_t))
```

takes about 0.51s

```
list comprehension: 0.5140271186828613s
```

This code uses **`joblib.Parallel()`** constructor :

```
start_t = time.time()
list_from_parallel = Parallel(n_jobs=2)(delayed(sqrt)(i ** 2) for i in range(1000000))
print('Parallel: {}s'.format(time.time() - start_t))
```

takes about 31s

```
Parallel: 31.3990638256073s
```

Why is that? Shouldn't `Parallel()` become faster than a non-paralleled computation?

Here is part of the **`cpuinfo`** :

```
processor       : 0
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 79
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU @ 2.20GHz
stepping        : 0
microcode       : 0x1
cpu MHz         : 2200.000
cache size      : 56320 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 8
core id         : 0
cpu cores       : 4
apicid          : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 13
wp              : yes
```

Answer (score 9):

> **Q** : *Shouldn't `Parallel()` become faster than a non-paralleled computation?*

Well, **that depends,** depends a lot on circumstances ( be it a `joblib.Parallel()` or other way ).

**There are no benefits that would ever come for free** <sub>( All such promises ***failed*** to deliver, since 1917 ... )</sub>

Plus,
it is very easy to happen to
**pay way more**  <sub>( on spawning processes for starting a multiprocessing )</sub>
**than you receive back** <sub>( speedup expected over an original workflow )</sub> ... so a due care is a must

---

### The best first step:

[**Revisit** the Amdahl's law](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18374629/3) revision and criticism about process-scheduling effects (speedup achieved form reorganisation of process-flows and using, at least in some part, a parallel process-scheduling).

The original Amdahl's formulation was not explicit on so called **add-on** ***"costs"*** one has to pay for going into parallel work-flows, that are not in the budget of the original, pure-`[SERIAL]` flow-of-work.

**1) Process-instantiations** was always expensive in python, as it first has to replicate as many copies (O/S-driven RAM-allocations sized for **`n_jobs`**(2)-copies + O/S-driven copying the RAM-image of the main python session) ( Thread-based multiprocessing does negative speedup, as there still remains GIL-lock re-`[SERIAL]`-isation of work-steps among all spawned threads, so you get nothing, while you have paid immense add-on costs for spawning + for each add-on GIL-ackquire/GIL-release step-dancing step - an awful antipattern for compute-intensive tasks, it may help mask some cases of I/O-related latencies, but definitely not a case for computing intensive workloads )

**2)** Add-on costs for **parameters' transfer** - you have to move some data from main process towards the new ones. It costs add-on time and you have to pay this add-on cost, that is not present in the original, pure-`[SERIAL]` workflow.

**3)** Add-on costs for **results return transfer** - you have to move some data from the new ones back to the originating (main) process. It costs add-on time and you have to pay this add-on cost, that is not present in the original, pure-`[SERIAL]` workflow.

**4)** Add-on costs for **any data interchange** ( better avoid any tempting to use this in parallel workflows - why? **a)** It blocks + **b)** It is expensive and you have to pay even more add-on costs for getting any further, which you do not pay in a pure-`[SERIAL]` original workflow ).

---

> **Q** : *Why does **`joblib.Parallel()`** take much more time than non-paralleled computation?*

Simply, because you have to pay way, way more to launch the whole orchestrated circus, than you will receive back from such parallel work-flow organisation ( too small amount of work in `math.sqrt( <int> )` to ever justify the relative-immense costs of spawning 2-full-copies of the original python-(main)-session + all the orchestration of dances to send just each and every ( `<int>` )-from-(main)-there and retrieving a returning each resulting ( `<float>` )-from-(joblib.Parallel()-process)-back-to-(main).

Your raw benchmarking times provide sufficient comparison of the accumulated costs to do the same result:

```
[SERIAL]-<iterator> feeding a [SERIAL]-processing storing into list[]:  0.51 [s]
[SERIAL]-<iterator> feeding [PARALLEL]-processing storing into list[]: 31.39 [s]
```

Raw estimate says **about 30.9 second were "*wasted*"** to do the same (small) amount of work just by forgetting about the add-on costs one has always to pay.

---

### So, how to measure *How Much You Have To Pay*  <sub>... before one has to pay it...</sub>?

Benchmark, benchmark, benchmark the actual code ... (prototype)

If interested in benchmarking these costs - how long does it take in **`[us]` ( i.e. How Much You Have To Pay**, before any useful work even starts ) to do 1), 2) or 3), [there were posted benchmarking templates to test](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A3666197%20%5Bparallelism-amdahl%5D%20is%3Aanswer) and validate these principal costs on one's own platform, before being able to decide, what is a minimum work-package, that can justify these un-avoidable expenses and yield a "positive" speedup any greater, ( best a lot greater ) `>> 1.0000` when compared to the pure-`[SERIAL]` original.

Comment: Would you please give a reproducible benchmarking templates you verified in person?