# Is there a way to estimate the Python interpreter overhead of the loop itself?

Tags: python, parallel-processing

This [post](https://towardsdatascience.com/why-you-should-forget-for-loop-for-data-science-code-and-embrace-vectorization-696632622d5f) says

> if the body of your loop is simple, the interpreter overhead of the loop itself can be a substantial amount of the overhead

and gives this [example](https://github.com/craffel/crucialpython/blob/master/week8/joblib_parallelization.ipynb) to illustrate Parallel.

```
def convolve_random(size):
    ''' Convolve two random arrays of length "size" '''
    return np.convolve(np.random.random_sample(size), np.random.random_sample(size))
%timeit convolve_random(40000)
1 loops, best of 3: 904 ms per loop

%timeit [convolve_random(40000 + i*1000) for i in xrange(8)]
# In parallel, with 8 jobs
%timeit Parallel(n_jobs=8)(delayed(convolve_random)(40000 + i*1000) for i in xrange(8))
1 loops, best of 3: 8.69 s per loop
1 loops, best of 3: 2.88 s per loop
```

in this case, is there a way to estimate the Python interpreter overhead of the loop itself?

Comment: You could try timing a loop with an empty body.

Comment: those links both go to the same place and it doesn't contain that quote.  that said, python should take a few nanoseconds per loop iteration.  this is many orders of magnitude smaller than your function

Comment: @SamMason Thanks for reminder. I've updated the OP. Does your "orders of magnitude" mean `An order of magnitude is an approximate measure of the number of digits that a number has in the commonly-used base-ten number system. It is equal to the whole number floor of logarithm (base 10). For example, the order of magnitude of 1500 is 3, because 1500 = 1.5 × 103.`?

Comment: @whnlp just consider that the difference is such that it makes the overhead negligeable for all practical considerations - if you need to worry about this overhead then the solution is most probably to switch to plain C - which is what libraries like numpy are doing FWIW, and which is why they are much faster than plain python loops.

Comment: yes., in this case the overhead you're worrying about (interpreter overhead) is approx. 6 orders of magnitude (i.e. a million times) smaller than the thing you care about (runtime of your function).  OP conventionally means "original poster", i.e. person who originally posted the question.

Answer (score 1):

> **Q** : *is there a way to estimate the Python interpreter overhead of the loop itself?*

You have already received the [answer 3 hours ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57710710/) for this, with directions for benchmarking templates, using **`[us]`**-resolution timings.

If you did not try the [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47551850/training-sklearn-models-in-parallel-with-joblib-blocks-the-process/47560341#47560341) test [templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47728862/why-does-the-get-operation-in-multiprocessing-pool-map-async-take-so-long/47731041#47731041) to measure it, go for it and you will receive hard data what are the looping costs ( best with beyond cache-size data-samples + avoiding the costs of `np.random.random()` generation ).

Comment: wow, your last answer is comprehensive...  @whnlp the *30.9 second were "wasted"* comment is basically the carry over for this question.  as a rough guide, I'd suggest aiming to do >10ms of work in each parallel job, and make sure you don't move too much data around as that can be expensive

Comment: What do [T0], [T0+tsB] and [T0+tsB+tpB] in [Revisit the Amdahl's law](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18374629/3) mean? What do "tsB", "tpB" stand for?

Comment: @whnlp In Fig.1, [T0] is a time,when either SEQ.A or SEQ.B pure-[SERIAL] processing start.The process-flow (A),labeled as SEQ.A,finishes the whole job at [T0+tsA] (after duration of tsA = **t**ime-of-**s**erial-processing-**A** [s]).The process-flow (B),consisting of both serial-part and parallel-part,labeled as SEQ.B, resp. PAR.B:<n>,finishes the whole job at [T0+tsB+tpB],after duration of tsB = **t**ime-of-**s**erial-processing-**B** [s] + duration of tpB = **t**ime-of-**p**aralel-processing-**B** [s],based on n~{1|2|4|8} resources R.i? being free & indivisible atomic-job duration "____."

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  Does "PAR-RESOURCE" mean the resources that could be used for parallel computing, such as processor core, multithread or a cluster of computers? Which one? Or could any one of them?